# QRegExp and double-quoted text for QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

What would the QRegExp pattern be for capturing quoted text for QSyntaxHighlighter?

**Test Pattern**

> "one" or "two" or "three"

So far I have tried:

```
QRegExp rx("\\0042.*\\0042");
QRegExp rx("(\\0042).*?\\1");
```

The last pattern succeeds on regexpal.com but not with the QRegExp class.

Comment: With or without the quotes?

Comment: The matches should include the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If you check out the [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html), already has this one in there.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter-highlighter-cpp.html

```
 quotationFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkGreen);
 rule.pattern = QRegExp("\".*\"");
 rule.format = quotationFormat;
 highlightingRules.append(rule);
```

Just copy most of the code from Qt's highlighter example and you should be set.

### Greedy v. Lazy Match in QRegEx

In the description of Qt's variation on RegEx, it says:

> Note: Quantifiers are normally "greedy". They always match as much text as they can. For example, 0+ matches the first zero it finds and all the consecutive zeros after the first zero. Applied to '20005', it matches'20005'. Quantifiers can be made non-greedy, see setMinimal().

If you use `setMinimal(true)` to get the effect of lazy matching instead of greedy matching, you can pull it off.  Other regex evaluators use something like `*?` or `+?` to perform a lazy match.  Sometimes I use [gskinner's regex engine](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test my expressions.

Below is the code you are looking for.  It is based heavily on the example given [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#indexIn).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString str = "\"one\" or \"two\" or \"three\"";

    QRegExp rx("\".*\"");
    rx.setMinimal(true);
     int count = 0;
     int pos = 0;
     while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
         ++count;
         pos += rx.matchedLength();
         qDebug() << rx.cap();
     }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope that helps.